# Opencart add new custom page to search results

Tags: search, opencart

I have been looking through many forums but I was unsuccessful :(

I need to display the content of a OpenCart custom page in the search page.

Ta very much

Comment: does the custom page has it's own controller ?

Comment: and what's your version of OC ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to execute that custom controller, save its output in the  data list of the search page template and display it there where ever you want

**(1)** Open the file "*<OC_ROOT>/catalog/controller/product/search.php*", you will find a class named "*ControllerProductSearch*", we are interested in the function "*index()*"

**(2)** Find the statement

```php
$this->children = array(
  'common/column_left',
  'common/column_right',
  'common/content_top',
  'common/content_bottom',
  'common/footer',
  'common/header'
);
```

**(3)** Add the route of your custom controller in the array `$this->children`, now OC will automatically evaluate your custom controller and send the HTML in a variable to the template, the variable name will be the last component in the route (e.g if your route is `common/my_customer_controller`, the name will be `$my_custome_controller`)

**(4)** Open the search page template file "*<OC_ROOT>/catalog/view/theme/<YOUR_THEME_FOLDER>/template/product/search.tpl*", and use the variable there

---

P.S. Make sure that you define your custom controller in the same way other controllers are defined (file naming style, class name based on the route ...), other wise the above solution won't work

Comment: Thank you Abdo, if successful will share with the stackoverflow community.

Comment: If not, tell me and I will try to fix it with you :D